# Mixing squared textboxes and rounded buttons

Tags: gui-design, input-fields, textbox

Is it bad UX to make rounded button and squared text box, and which is the best to do?

[image: Sample with squared corner text field and curved button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue it's good UX.

The 'rounded' button is clearly a button because of those rounded corners.

The form fields could have rounded corners, but I'd argue it's superfluous and wouldn't be adding any value beyond a MILD aesthetic and few more lines of code.